# Can't install wordcloud in anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, installation, anaconda, data-science

Solving environment: failed

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - wordcloud
>     - xlsxwriter Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package

.

Initially i get conflict with `python 3.4` and `python 3.6` so update `python` to `3.6` but still getting above erroe. Pls help

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/246

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pip install wordcloud
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried those options answered above. I think there was some problem with with Anaconda python 3.x versions. I used 2.7 and it worked fine there for me

Answer (score 0):

Using Anaconda Python 3.6 version For Windows you can do it as:

Installation of wordcloud package
download wordcloud‑1.3.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl from
[http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud)
Copy the file to your current working directory
Open command prompt
python -m pip install wordcloud-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

You can use according to your python version. Don't need to migrate into another python version.

Answer (score -1):

In console :
`conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud`

**First activate your python environment !**